# List of Windows application's exit codes

Tags: windows, exit-code

Where can I get the list of Windows application's exit codes?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

An application can specify any exit code it wants. The convention is that zero indicates no error, but other than that there is no standard.

Did you perhaps mean Win32 **error** codes ? Those are in winerror.h, and documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I will try to explain more precisely.
Application ends with "return -1". How can I monitor it with another application?

Comment: Assuming you started the process, you call GetExitCodeProcess. Read up on the APIs for CreateProcess (or ShellExecuteEx), WaitForSingleObject, GetExitCodeProcess. Code for launch-and-wait is on my website here: http://bobmoore.mvps.org/Win32/w32tip58.htm 

Imagine adding a call to GetExitCodeProcess once that wait has completed.